# How to search result set from a result set in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im tring to understand the DSL query i needed if i want to make a search from a result set i got. means i have an initial term search, then i want make another query upon the previous result.

lets say i a have 10 documents with a sharing identifier between them, each document has a description field. i want to search first all the documents containing the value 'Hello' in the description and then take their id's, and search the document containing the value 'good by'.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to execute two queries, you can use filter context that will filter out the results.`filter` parameter will filter out documents that do not match, and will also not affect the score for matching documents.

> Filter context is in effect whenever a query clause is passed to a
> filter parameter, such as the filter or must_not parameters in the
> bool query, the filter parameter in the constant_score query, or the
> filter aggregation.

Refer this to know more about [Query and Filter contexts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)

Comment: Lets say i have 2 documents related by their share_id field.

[
  {
    "share_id": 123,
    "description": "hello"
  },
  {
    "share_id": 123,
    "description": "good by"
  }
]

i need to find if the are documents related by their ids that must have the hello and good by in their description, note that they are different documents but with the same id